# Program doesn't import coordinates like it should

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am a student.

This program i have been working on it for 2 weeks i need help to run it.

It doesn't import coordinates like it should.

I have posted coordinates on my previous question.

After getting the path it simply displays:

`enter at least 3 sides`

then closes

I am supposed to

- import coordinates which are (x,y) at least 3.
- Compute area
- print the massage displaying area and polygon type.

```python
 def getcoord():
        '''this function read coordinates from a csv file'''
        
        myfile= input('Enter the path of file : ')
        filename = 'CoordsT.txt'
        with open('filename', 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            next(reader)
            return list(reader)
            data=[]
            for row in reader:
                Name=row[0]
                E=float(row[1])
                N=float(row[2])
                data.append([Name,E,N])
            return data
    
    def areacalculation(data): #function that calculate the area of polygon,returns area and no of side
        n=len(data)
        semiarea= 0.0
        j = n - 1
        if n>=3:
            for i in range(0,n):
                semiarea += (float(data[j][1] + data[i][1]) * (data[j][2]- data[i][2]))
                j = i #j is previous vertex to i
            return float(abs(semiarea / 2.0))
        else:
            print('Enter  at least 3 sides of polygon')
    
    def No_ofsides(polytyp):
        polygontype = No_ofsides
        return No_ofsides
   
    
    def polygontype(n): #function that gives the type of polygon, takes argument
        my_dict={3:'Triangle', 4:'Quadrilateral', 5:'Pentagon', 6:'Hexagon', 7:'Heptagon', 8:'Octagon', 9:'Nonagon', 10:'Decagon'}
        return my_dict.items()
    
    def square_metre(area):     #function with argument
        A2=area
        return (A2)
        
    def hectares(area):   # fuction with argument
        A1=area 
        return ("% .4f".format(A1))
    
def main():
    instruction()
    data = getcoord()
    a =areacalculation(data)
    hectares(a)
    sqm=square_metre(a)
    polytyp=polygontype(No_ofsides)
    #area_hec=a/10000.00
    
    if a<=10000.00:
        print('The area of: {}, is, {}.'.format('polytyp, hectares'))
    else:
        print('The area of: {}, is, {}.'.format('polytyp, square_metre'))
   
main()
```

Comment: use string::format to display text with numbers, why is there a `return` in the middle of `main()`, Look at `No_ofsides` and `polygontype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the big things in assignments like this is to get a framework that is working and go from there.  I tweaked only a few parts of your code and put in some print statements.  Try this out as a start...

Getting the area from a list of points can be a challenge unless you have some guarantees about the order of the points received.  Perhaps your assignment has some additional information you can use.

This will at least get things going as it runs without errors and reads the file and exercises your functions.

```
import csv

def getcoord():
        '''this function read coordinates from a csv file'''
        
        # myfile= input('Enter the path of file : ')  # let's start by hard-coding this for testing
        filename = 'points.csv'
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:          # filename here is a variable, not a string
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            # next(reader)
            # return list(reader)   # what is this?
            data=[]
            for row in reader:      # Good!  this is the way to go!
                Name=row[0]
                E=float(row[1])
                N=float(row[2])
                data.append([Name,E,N])

            return data
    
def areacalculation(data): #function that calculate the area of polygon,returns area and no of side
    return -1  # this is a dummy value just to get your code running
    n=len(data)
    semiarea= 0.0
    j = n - 1
    if n>=3:
        for i in range(0,n):
            semiarea += (float(data[j][1] + data[i][1]) * (data[j][2]- data[i][2]))
            j = i #j is previous vertex to i
        return float(abs(semiarea / 2.0))
    else:
        print('Enter  at least 3 sides of polygon')

# def No_ofsides(polytyp):
#   polygontype = No_ofsides
#   return No_ofsides


def polygontype(data): #function that gives the type of polygon, takes argument
    num_sides = len(data)
    my_dict={3:'Triangle', 4:'Quadrilateral', 5:'Pentagon', 6:'Hexagon', 7:'Heptagon', 8:'Octagon', 9:'Nonagon', 10:'Decagon'}
    return my_dict.get(num_sides)

def square_metre(area):     #function with argument
    A2=area
    return (A2)
    
def hectares(area):   # fuction with argument
    A1=area 
    return ("% .4f".format(A1))
    
def main():
    # instruction()
    data = getcoord()
    # let's do a little check here.... we can comment this out later
    print('data read: ', data)
    a = areacalculation(data)
    print('area calculated: ', a)
    # hectares(a)
    # sqm=square_metre(a)
    polytyp=polygontype(data)     # just send this function your data and let it do the work!
    print('polygon type described: ', polytyp)
    #area_hec=a/10000.00
    
    # if a<=10000.00:
    #   print('The area of: {}, is, {}.'.format('polytyp, hectares'))
    # else:
    #   print('The area of: {}, is, {}.'.format('polytyp, square_metre'))
   
main()
```

#### Output:

```
data read:  [['A', 10.0, 10.0], ['B', 10.0, 20.0], ['C', 20.0, 20.0], ['D', 20.0, 10.0]]
area calculated:  -1
polygon type described:  Quadrilateral
```

#### datafile I used for this:

```
A, 10, 10
B, 10, 20
C, 20, 20
D, 20, 10
```